# ¿Como enviar Texto de Listboxt por GET?

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy pasando algunos parámetros utilizando javascript por medio de GET a mi controlador. Uno de ellos es un campo de tipo `listboxt(select)`, sin embargo no logro conseguir el valor del texto seleccionado para mostrarlo en mi resultado, si no mas bien el texto que me muestra es `[object Object]`

¿Como puedo pasar el valor del texto de forma correcta? De antemano gracias.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btn_buscar').on('click', function(){

      var fecha_ini =  $("#fecha_ini").val();
      var fecha_ter =  $("#fecha_ter").val();
      var rut_usu =  $("#rut_usu").val() ;
      var jc = $("#rut_usu").val($( "#rut_usu option:selected" ).text());


     window.open('<?php echo base_url();?>C_Porcentaje/tabla_porcentaje?fecha_ini=' + fecha_ini + '&fecha_ter=' + fecha_ter + '&rut_usu=' + rut_usu + '&jc=' + jc);

      });

    });

  </script>
```

Comment: Prueba haciéndolo así: `var jc = $( "#rut_usu option:selected" ).text();`

Comment: Quedo perfecto, gracias, podrías colocarlo  como respuesta para dejarlo como solución por favor?

Comment: Claro, ya está !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para seleccionar el texto de la etiqueta `option` seleccionada no es necesario seleccionar primero el valor del `select` y luego el texto del `option` como lo estás haciendo, ¡estabas muy cerca de lograrlo! solo basta con hacer lo siguiente:

```
var jc = $( "#rut_usu option:selected" ).text();
```